# Flash - Using classes

Tags: flash, class

I have the following code and get the following error:

Errors:
Call to possibly undefined method addFrameScript
Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
The class 'player' muset subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import CollisionObject;

public class player extends CollisionObject {

    public function player() {
        // constructor code
        trace("I am an player");
    } //end constructor
}//end class
```

} //end package

Here is the assignment: http://www.lwebdesigns.net/school/WGB340_WK3_iLab_corrected_MAR13.docx

I am stuck on step 2-3

Comment: Extend `CollisionObject` as a MovieClip.

Comment: Thank you, that got rid of a lot of errors!